# Change dataframe column values at one go using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to make the below changes in python at one go. Can we do it in one statement using replace/map ?

```
data['CATEGORY'][(data.CATEGORY == 'Miscellaneous') & (data.SUB_CAT == 'Helipad')] = "Transport Services" <br>
data['CATEGORY'][(data.CATEGORY == 'Miscellaneous') & (data.SUB_CAT == 'Restaurant')] = "Fooding & Lodging Services" <br>
data['CATEGORY'][(data.CATEGORY == 'Miscellaneous') & (data.SUB_CAT == 'Pharmacy')] = "Emergency Services" <br>
data['CATEGORY'][(data.CATEGORY == 'Miscellaneous') & (data.SUB_CAT == 'Blood Bank')] = "Emergency Services" <br>
data['CATEGORY'][(data.CATEGORY == 'Miscellaneous') & (data.SUB_CAT == 'Godown')] = "Commercial Services" <br>
data['CATEGORY'][(data.CATEGORY == 'Miscellaneous') & (data.SUB_CAT == 'Factory')] = "Industries" <br>
```

Comment: Use dictionary in a loop.

Comment: Yeah I know dictionary would help. But I am confused as there are multiple conditions. Can you please let me know the structure of the dictionary that will be of use

Comment: create a function with these specific rules then use the df.apply function to loop over the dataframe

Comment: Maybe a list of tuples is enough no need for a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Single criterion

If you are looking only to update rows with "Miscellaneous":

```
d = {'Helipad': 'Transport Services',
     'Restaurant': 'Fooding & Lodging Services'}

mask = data['CATEGORY'] == 'Miscellaneous'
df.loc[mask, 'CATEGORY'] = df.loc[mask, 'SUB_CAT'].map(d)
```

#### Multiple criteria

Construct a dictionary with a structure mapping criteria to value:

```
d = {('Miscellaneous', 'Helipad'): 'Transport Services',
     ('Miscellaneous', 'Restaurant'): 'Fooding & Lodging Services'}
```

Then use `pd.Series.map`:

```
# extract series of tuples
tups = data.set_index(['CATEGORY', 'SUB_CAT']).index.to_series()
# alternatively:
# tups = pd.Series(list(zip(data['CATEGORY'], data['SUB_CAT'])))

# map series to values
data['CATEGORY'] = tups.map(d).fillna(data['CATEGORY'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer @jpp .. But getting the error as  "initializing a Series from a MultiIndex is not supported", while executing tups = pd.Series(data.set_index(['CATEGORY', 'SUB_CAT']).index)

Comment: @SandeepGupta, I've updated with 2 alternatives which may help.

Comment: First part works, but somehow Multiple Criteria isn't working. Thanks for your help @jpp. You gave me a bit of insight to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might help you:

```
l = [('Helipad', "Transport Services"), ...]

for item in l:
    data['CATEGORY'][(data.CATEGORY == 'Miscellaneous') & (data.SUB_CAT == item[0])] = item[1]
```

Comment: This is good as well, but when it comes to processing 130M records it will take a lot of time. But thanks a lot for taking your time out to help me on this @ARMAN